# How to overwrite material-ui className with aphrodite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, aphrodite

I'm using React and styling some icons.  I'm using the [Material-UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) library for my components.  One of the components I'm using is the [FontIcon](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/FontIcon) .  It already has a className on it, and I'm not able to override with my passed in aphrodite style.

```js
<FontIcon className="material-icons">
    bug_report
</FontIcon>
```

If I set the style on this control, it works fine:

```js
<FontIcon className="material-icons" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
  bug_report
</FontIcon>
```

How can you over-write an existing className?  I've tried:

```
className={css(['material-icons', styles.colorize])}
className={css('material-icons', styles.colorize)}
className={('material-icons', css(styles.colorize))}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this component doesn't allow to pass a custom `className` property, only the ability to extend with the `style` one as you can see in their [PropTypes definition](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/FontIcon/FontIcon.js#L30).

Material-ui is using a style in JS form, and doesn't really want to deal with "normal" CSS, even though I agree sometimes it's easier to override.

You could wrap your component in a div that you give your custom `className` and stylize the children instead. Appart from doing a pull request, there is not much choice.

Comment: Wrapping it doesn't seem to work.  Can't win them all :)

Comment: I was saying something like wrap the icon in a div, give the div a `className `and then stylize it using `.yourclass > span`, it should work with `!important` ;)